# auto-accepting a Mercurial change chunk

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I have a very large repo with thousands of files that can regularly get updated by automatic processes that are out of my control (this is for Unity 3D, for what it's worth).

For example, if I upgrade Unity to a new version, it will reimport all textures and maybe add a line in thousands of .meta files that correspond to a new serialized data that didn't exist previously.

Obviously reviewing thousands of files is terrible. Most of the time though, I can quickly identify a particular diff, and would just like to automatically check all the files that have the same diff, commit to get them out of the way, and see what's left: other diffs that I might not know about.

For example I just commited 4000+ files that all contained this diff:
[image]

So the pattern would be easy to find:

```
-  textureFormat: -5
+  textureFormat: -1
```

I suppose I could write a script, or a TortoiseHg tool to do that, I just have no idea where to begin. I'd need to iterate over all changed files/chunks, match a pattern, commit the chunks...

Answer (score 1):

I know of no tool to do exactly what you want. However I believe it's relatively easy to write a small bash script for such or use the command line:

```
hg diff --nodates --noprefix -U 0 | grep '^+' | grep -v '+++' | sort | uniq -c
```

will list you the inserted lines of the current diff in descending order of the number of occurences, thus the most frequently occurring diff first.

With that list you get a list of files which match the newly inserted pattern, for instance

```
hg files "set:grep('^ textureFormat: -1')"
```

should give you all files with that pattern (whether it's new or not, though). You probably want to check those files, whether their diff contains anything else:

```
hg diff "set:grep('^  textureFormat: -1')"
```

Now you can make use of the results and even exclude single files, if the diff output didn't suit you:

```
hg commit "set:grep('^ textureFormat: -1') and not 'unwantedFilename.cpp'"
```

In the above commands I made use of the fileset capability and of `hg grep` which accepts regular expressions. Check `hg help grep`, `hg help fileset` and `hg help patterns` for a more in-depth explanation.